# Jekyll doesn't compile scss files with `jekyll serve`

Tags: sass, jekyll

I'm trying to create a website using Jekyll, and everything worked fine. Until I wanted to custom the design.

I've updated my `css/main.scss` in order to include my custom theme in `_sass/theme.scss`:

```
// Import partials from `sass_dir` (defaults to `_sass`)
@import
        "base",
        "layout",
        "syntax-highlighting",
        "theme"
;
```

I've also updated `_config.yml`, because `jekyll serve -H 0.0.0.0` didn't compile my new sass file. I've added the following:

```
sass:
    sass_dir: _sass
```

The problem is `jekyll serve` doesn't compile my sass files, I always see the default css. I've also tried to copy the content of `_sass/theme.scss` directly at the end of `css/main.scss`, but nothing happened.

Until I modified one of those files while `jekyll serve` was running. The thing is `jekyll-watch` understands my updates and compile the scss files. May I have done something wrong for `jekyll build` don't compile sass files at the first try?

In case you need it, here my project tree:

```
.
├── _config.yml
├── css
│   ├── main.css
│   └── main.scss
├── _images
├── img
├── index.html
└── _sass
    ├── _base.scss
    ├── _layout.scss
    ├── _syntax-highlighting.scss
    └── _theme.scss
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you have a repository where we can get and test your code ?

Comment: I do, you can find it here: [github.com/bj0rge](https://github.com/bj0rge/bjorge.xyz/tree/sassTest)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I get it !

You have a `css/main.css` files that is copied as a static file in `_site/css/main.css`.

The problem is that it has the same name as the `css/main.scss` target which is also `_site/css/main.css`.

So at first build :

- `css/main.scss` is processed to `main.css`
- then, when static files are copied, it is overridden by `css/main.css`.

Solution : delete `css/main.css`

Comment: It works, thank you very much! The strange thing is that `css/main.css` and `css/main.scss` were both generated by `jekyll new myblog` command, so if there is a conflict between the files, why create both of them?

Comment: `jekyll new myblog` doesn't create `css/main.css`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you added the front matter to the top of your main.scss file?

Comment: Yes, my `main.scss` file starts with two lines of three dashes.

Answer (score 4):

First add to your config.yml

```
sass:
    sass_dir: _sass
```

Then add to top in your main.scss file,  two dashed lines https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/

```
---
---

@charset "utf-8";
```

After that write in your cmd console

> jekyll serve

and check your compilation.

Comment: I've already done that, but [@david-jacquel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437416/jekyll-doesnt-compile-scss-files-with-jekyll-serve#answer-38442415) figured out what was wrong. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues when trying to use Jekyll to pass YAML content into partials. It looks like this workflow is not possible.

The work around was to place all variables on the main SCSS file and get Jekyll to populate the values from YAML, then using partials for the actual styles.

Here's a simple repo with some of my solutions: https://github.com/guschiavon/jekyllfy-sass