# How to use scss in jekyll?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I saw similar posts on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437416/jekyll-doesnt-compile-scss-files-with-jekyll-serve) and on GH [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/281), but neither solved the issue that I have.

I have a Jekyll app on my gh pages where I needed to use scss features (mostly for mixins). However, I could not get jekyll to work with scss.

Currently, this is where my (CSS) files are at. All of my CSS are taken from `custom.css`. I imported it in header `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/stylesheets/custom.css">`.

[image: folders]

The `.scss` files inside `_sass` folder are empty.

This is what it looks like inside `_config.yml`:

```
...
#sass
sass:
  sass_dir:           _sass
  style:              compressed
```

That's where I am at now. Here are some things I have tried:

1. I have tried changing `custom.css` into `custom.scss` (and then updated the header `<link href... stylesheets/custom.scss">`. When I do that, I get `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/x-scss...` error.
2. I tried changing the configuration inside `_config.yml` into:

     `sass:
       sass_dir:           assets/stylesheets
       style:              compressed`

   ... and kept the changes from 1. I restarted `jekyll server`. However I still get `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/x-scss...` error.
3. Tried adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/_sass/main.scss">`, but I get `GET http://localhost:4000/_sass/main.scss` error.

The problem, I noticed, is that the app seem to not recognize `main.scss` at all. I tried to create a simple red-colored div with `main.scss`, but nothing was displayed.

The question is, how can I use `.scss` with Jekyll?

Comment: A **repository url** is a plus to help debug.

Answer (score 9):

Having `_sass/main.scss`, in `assets/stylesheets/custom.css` add the `sass` file (keep three dashes at the beginning):

```
---
---

@import "main";
```

Now you can work with all your sass variables/mixins etc in `custom.css` below the import keyword.

Make sure you add the generated `css` to your layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'/assets/stylesheets/custom.css' | absolute_url}}">
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the dashes?

Comment: @M.Volf needed for Jekyll to process the file.

Comment: the dashes are basically empty "front matter"